# Equivalent norm in $C[a, b]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is are equivalent the sup norm and the L1 norm in  $C([a,b],R)$? 
How can we show?

Answer (score 2):

$f_n(x)=(\frac {x-a} {b-a})^{n} \to 0$ in $L^{1}$ norm but not in sup norm.

$L^{1}$ convergence follows by direct computation of  the integral of $f_n$. [$\int_a^{b}f_n(x)dx=\frac {b-a} {n+1}$].

Note that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for $a \leq x <b$ and $f_n(b) =1$ for  all $n$. Since the limit function is not continuous the sequence cannot converge uniformly.

Comment: How can we show this?

Comment: @Rose Proof added.

Comment: I was computation $$(b-a)/(n+1)$$ integral of $$fn$$ How was 0 integral of $$fn$$

Comment: $\int_a^{b} f_n(x)dx=\frac {b-1} n \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. This means $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$ norm.

Comment: @R Yes, it is right. ($b -1$ was a typo in my comment. I meant $b-a$).

Comment: $$\int_a^{b} \frac {(x-a)^n}  {(b-a)^n} dx=\frac {1} {(b-a)^n} \int_a^{b} (x-a)^n dx=\frac {(x-a)^n (x-a)}  {(b-a)^n (n+1)} |=\frac{b-a} {n+1}$$ Is not it right?

Comment: Ok. Thank you very very much...